# How to get the SerialNumber of MAC Laptop in QT

Tags: ios, qt

I am developing a desktop application for OSX using QT.
How can i get the serial number of the OSX machine using QT API's.

Comment: yes i want it for all MAC OS

Comment: Mac laptops run Mac OS, not iOS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution in QT

```
     QProcess proc;
     QStringList args;
     args << "-c" << "ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice |  awk '/IOPlatformSerialNumber/ { print $3; }'";
     proc.start( "/bin/bash", args );
     proc.waitForFinished();
     QString uID = proc.readAll();
     qDebug()<<uID;
```

uId is the serial number